# Linq Group By Key seems to be "expanding" my result set

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

```
public class Sale 
{
    public List<LineItem> LineItems { get;set; }
    // more stuff
}

public class LineItem 
{
    public int SellerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Sale Sale { get; set; }
    // more stuff
}

IEnumerable<LineItem>lineItems = db.GetLineItemsBySellerId(sellerId).ToList();

IOrderedEnumerable<IGrouping<Sale, LineItem>>sales = lineItems.GroupBy(l => l.Sale);

foreach(var s in sales)
{
  var lines = s.Key.LineItems.ToList();
  DoSomething(lines);
}
```

I have a sale with 3 line items, from 2 different sellers.

Suppose I get two lineItems, but when I group them by Sale I get the whole sale which of course includes all 3 lineItems. I don't want this. I just want the 2 lineItems to be grouped so I have access to the sale data.

Is this possible?

Comment: If `GetLineItemsBySellerId` returns only the items for this seller the `GroupBy` will not yield items which don't belong to this seller. So you have a problem elsewhere

Comment: But I do and I broke the clauses down to confirm. As the Key of the result is a Sale, so when you look at it you see all line items for that Sale.

Comment: You have to show `GetLineItemsBySellerId`, i guess it does not filter all `List<LineItem>`. Note that `var` does not help to understand the types, what does `GetLineItemsBySellerId` return?

Comment: GetLineItemsBySellerId is returning 2 results. It looks like this:
db.LineItemRepository.Get().Where(l => l.SellerId == sellerId)

Comment: also, what property is `Sale` which you use for the `GroupBy`, is it a property returning your custom class? Have you overridden `Equals` and `GetHashCode`? You leave out many relevant informations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you have

```
foreach(var g in sales)
{
  var sale = g.Key;
  DoSomething(sale.lineItems);
}
```

You need to instead do:

```
foreach(var g in sales)
{
  var sale = g.Key;
  var lines = g.ToList();
  DoSomething(lines);
}
```

Comment: You've nailed it. Instead of g.ToList() I was using g.Key.LineItems.ToList()